# httpd server is not starting

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, failover

I am implementing failover mechanism in JBoss from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/194355/how-to-configure-failover-for-jboss-as-5)

I added following line in httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
```

Now I am getting following error while starting Apache

```
D:\Installation\apache-2\bin>httpd -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 495 of D:/Installation/apache-2/conf/httpd.conf: Can
not load D:/Installation/apache-2/modules/mod_jk.so into server: The specified
procedure could not be found.
```

I am sure that there is file mod_jk.so in modules directory. What could be reason for this and how to resolve this problem?
I am using Wondows 7 OS. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You're using Windows, but you're configuring Unix pathnames, and the wrong one at that.

Figure out where that **.dll** is placed on your system, and configure the path properly.

Also, all modules *must* be built for the specific apache version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For which dll file you are saying?

Comment: `*.so` files are meant for Linux/Unix platforms, you should find a DLL file (I'm guessing `mod_jk.dll`) as adaptr said.

Comment: Apache on Windows uses ".so" filenames for the DLLs. This issue seems to be a missing mod_jk.so file.